# Does Sassafras Sawdust Make A Good "Brown" For Kitchen Composting?

Tags: indoors, compost, soil-amendment

I've read Sassafras is a slow decomposing wood.

Comment: I doubt that it is significantly different from most. I have several sassafras in the yard and some have died; Their stumps rot the same as oak ,pine, or sweet gum, etc. However ,when cutting their roots there is a strong smell of "root beer".